# phonegap 3.4 unable to set an application name other than HelloWorld

Tags: android, cordova

I followed the docs and trying to create a new project with this command

```
phonegap create project --name "MyProject" --id "com.app.MyProject"
```

No matter how many times i try, the app is getting installed with "HellWorld" name.
I had to explicitly change res/values/strings.xml to `<string name="app_name">MyProject</string>` to alter the app name on the device.

Thanks in advance

Comment: To solve this problem, I have uninstalled phonegap 3.4.0 , installed version 3.3.0 , created and built a project  , and then upgrade to 3.4.0. This way I was able to keep my app name to the one I chose .

Answer (score 2):

The way I solve; I create project with 3.4 and then in adt I right clicked on the HelloWorld folder and refactor -> change name. I typed new application name. Even if adt have some null exception errors, I hit f5 a couple of times to refresh folders of newly created project. Then close and restarted the adt and voila! it started to work. And then I change application namespace from com.phonegap.helloworld -> com.mydomain.myappname. I know it is not logical but it is the way how I did. Hope this helps.

Comment: Isn't this a potential bug in 3.4.0 ?

Comment: I believe so, even in their documentation they have no information about this, and another bug is that opening link in a new browser window is not working, looking for workaround.